# Error while customizing B2C accelerator in hybris 5.7

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, b2b

I had followed the below link to install B2B & B2C store parallelly

```
https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?spaceKey=accdoc&title=Installing+B2C+and+B2B+Accelerators+in+Parallel
```

After, following the steps, I was able to get OOB electronics and powertools store.

Now, I am going to create my own custom B2C store by using modulegen.

But, I am getting error as:

```
    Trying to override old definition of task lesscss
Trying to override old definition of task movelibs
Trying to override old definition of task generatevariables

modulegen:
    [input]
    [input] Please choose a template for generation.
    [input] Press [Enter] to use the default value (acceleratorordermanagement, [accelerator], chinaaccelerator, commercewebservices, b2baccelerator)

    [input]
    [input] Please choose the name of your module extension. It has to start with a letter followed by letters and/or numbers.
    [input] Press [Enter] to use the default value [training]
merchandise
    [input]
    [input] Please choose the base package name of your extensions. It has to fulfill java package name convention. Each extension in the module will add its name to this package.
    [input] Press [Enter] to use the default value [org.training]
de.hybris.merchandise
     [echo] Using extension template source: C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\bin\ext-template\yacceleratorcore
     [echo] Using extension template source: C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\bin\ext-template\yacceleratorfacades
     [echo] Using extension template source: C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\bin\custom\yb2bacceleratorstorefront
     [echo] Using extension template source: C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\bin\ext-template\yacceleratortest
     [echo] Using extension template source: C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\bin\ext-template\yacceleratorstorefront
     [echo] Using extension template source: C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\bin\ext-template\yacceleratorfulfilmentprocess
     [echo] Using extension template source: C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\bin\ext-template\yacceleratorinitialdata
     [echo] Using extension template source: C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\bin\ext-template\yacceleratorcockpits
     [echo] Processing extension yacceleratorcore
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\temp\hybris\extgen\yacceleratorcore
     [echo] Copying template files from C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\bin\ext-template\yacceleratorcore to C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\temp\hybris/extgen/yacceleratorcore
     [copy] Copying 474 files to C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\temp\hybris\extgen\yacceleratorcore
     [echo] Replacing tokens in template files: C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\temp\hybris/extgen
  [replace] Replaced 428 occurrences in 100 files.
     [copy] Copying 474 files to C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\temp\hybris\extgen_final\yacceleratorcore
     [echo] Processing extension yacceleratorfacades
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\temp\hybris\extgen\yacceleratorfacades
     [echo] Copying template files from C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\bin\ext-template\yacceleratorfacades to C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\temp\hybris/extgen/yacceleratorfacades
     [copy] Copying 70 files to C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\temp\hybris\extgen\yacceleratorfacades
     [echo] Replacing tokens in template files: C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\temp\hybris/extgen
  [replace] Replaced 117 occurrences in 40 files.
     [copy] Copying 70 files to C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\temp\hybris\extgen_final\yacceleratorfacades
     [echo] Processing extension yb2bacceleratorstorefront

BUILD FAILED
C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\bin\platform\build.xml:121: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\modulegen.xml:324: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\modulegen.xml:330: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\modulegen.xml:45: extgen.properties in source extension not found! this is not a template!

Total time: 22 seconds

C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\bin\platform>
```

localextension.xml:

```
<extension name='mcc' />
     <extension name='backoffice' />
     <extension name='commercesearchbackoffice' />

     <extension name='commerceservicesbackoffice' />
     <extension name='solrfacetsearchbackoffice' />

     <extension name='yacceleratorcockpits' />
     <extension name='yacceleratorinitialdata' />
     <extension name='yacceleratorfulfilmentprocess' />
     <extension name='yacceleratorstorefront' />
     <extension name='yaddon' />
     <extension name='ycommercewebservices' />

     <extension name="electronicsstore"/>
     <extension name="apparelstore"/>
     <extension name='solrserver' />
     <extension name='liveeditaddon' />
     <extension name='acceleratorwebservicesaddon' />

      <extension name='powertoolsstore' />
     <extension name='b2bcommercebackoffice' />
      <extension name='b2badmincockpit' />
     <extension name='b2bacceleratoraddon' />
     <extension name='commerceorgaddon' />

     <extension dir="C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\bin/custom/yb2bacceleratorstorefront"/>
```

Comment: Where's the error? I can't see an error in modulegen?

Comment: @MikePalfrey Its showing build failed...i had updated my question above..

Answer (score 1):

Its because you have that new, custom, yb2bacceleratorstorefront extension in your custom folder, and this is autoloading due to the line above your snippet of localextensions.xml.

This extension is then trying to get involved in the modulegen as it contains the same modulegen key due to you just generating from it, but is no longer a template as you generated it.

You should be doing the modulegen first. Then, generate as many additional storefronts as you like. But bear in mind these are just tools to help you out, and if you want to do more complex things you'll have to figure out how.

Comment: Thanks for the update ! Once you finish with your storefronts, can you just move back the yb2bacceleratorstorefront  to the custom folder instead of re-installing it ?

Answer (score 1):

With above solutions you also cheek this.

You have one  custom extension- yb2bacceleratorstorefront. Kindly check its `extensioninfo.xml`, You may find below line

```
meta key="modulegen-name" value="accelerator,b2baccelerator,chinaaccelerator"
```

Commenting this line solved the problem for me.

Comment: Commenting worked for me:  meta key="modulegen-name" value="accelerator

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, but I suspect that this is a path issue.

```
<extension dir="C:\hybris-commerce-suites-5.7.0.3\hybris\bin/custom/yb2bacceleratorstorefront"/>
```

Does it exist? Try loading the extension by name - e.g.

```
<extension name="yb2bacceleratorstorefront"/>
```

If this works, then it points at an issue with loading the extension based on the directory (most likely an incorrect path).

Comment: Does it build without your extension included? Does the extgen.properties file exist in your extension?

Comment: yes it is building without extension...and yes extgen.properties files also exists...

Comment: Check your file permissions and ensure the extgen.properties exists for the yb2bacceleratorstorefront. Looking at the modulegen.xml on 5.7 the code that's erroring is pretty straightforward - it's looking for extgen.properties inside yb2bacceleratorstorefront and can't find it, so I still suspect it's something to do with files/permissions.